# After installing Teradata SQL Assistant v15.10.03 on Citrix (Windows 2012), some users are unable to launch the application via citrix

Tags: windows, installation, teradata, citrix

We have recently installed Teradata SQL assistant which was part of TTU v15.10.03 on Citrix server. Some users(not all) are facing the issue where it says path to ansiAF.mbr is denied. Any idea why this could be?

[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdHsj.png)

Comment: Last I knew, Teradata SQL Assistant was never officially certified for Citrix. You may want to open an incident with the Teradata Global Support Center if no one here has any insight. FWIW, the latest version of Teradata Studio was certified for Citrix, which is the eventual replacement for SQL Assistant.

Comment: The error message seems to be due to the syntax highlighting in SQLA. Due to unknown reasons (related to Citrix) the files defining the keywords for different DBMSes can't be accessed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I upgraded from v13 to v15. Installed on my computer (not Citrix), hope this gives some clue to resolve yours.

Went to this location, 
"C:\Users*user-id*\AppData\Roaming\Teradata"
renamed the already present folder 'SQL Assistant' to 'SQL Assistant - Backup'.

Reran SQLA, the folder 'SQL Assistant' got created again. And error is resolved.

**However all customizations and history from v13 will go!**  To get back the history, copy SQLHistory.mdb file from backup folder and replace in the newly created one.